# Why is the CSS height percentage not working

Tags: html, css

I have some simple CSS and I don't know why it isn't working. It uses percentages and I have labeled both and I still don't understand why it works. Here's the code

```css
.BoxHeight {
height: 100%;
}

#Box {
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="BoxHeight">
<div id="Box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working? What are you trying to accomplish? Seems to be working for me.

Comment: Check the height of <div class="BoxHeight"></div> 's parent

Answer (score 2):

You need to add height to the body.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do "BoxHeight" have a parent ? Be cause if no, or the parent is a default body, it will have a height of 0. You must give a diffined Height, using px for exemple, and the "Box" will have 80% of this height.

Comment: The Parent is the div called BoxHeight

Comment: But does the "BoxHeight" have a parent ?